# MongoDB retrieve and update object in array, inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I found a lot of questions on accessing arrays in arrays and object in arrays but I couldn't find anything exactly on this.
I'm working with NodeJS and MongoDb, this is an example of the document "airlines" I am using. I am attempting to retrieve and edit the flight objects inside the array of capture objects.

```
{
    "_id": "548653018d49c56c1fc11425",
    "name": "British Airways",
    "icao": "BAW",
    "captures": [{
        "startDate": 1417910400,
        "endDate": 1417996800,
        "flights": [{
            "ident": "BAW7411",
            "departuretime": 1417910400             
        },
        {
            "ident": "BAW7411",             
            "departuretime": 1417910400             
        }]
    }]
}
```

What should my query look like if I want to retrieve the flight object with the "ident" value of "BAW7411" and the "departuretime" value of "1417910400"? I've tried many variations of the following:

```
db.collection('airlines', {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({"captures": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "flights" : {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "ident": "BAW7411",
                        "departuretime": "1417910400"
                    }
                }                       
            }
        }
    }, function(result, response){  
        printJSON(result);
    }); 
});
```